# Как задать интервал работы скрипта по клику?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

Добрый день. Написал слайдер. Все хорошо, остался только если пользователь нажимает слишком быстро ( быстрее чем задана анимация) появляется нежелательный баг. Подскажите у меня такой код, как я могу сделать что бы клик срабатывал не чаще раз в 0.5секунд( столько длиться анимация)

```
ButtonNext.addEventListener('click',
// CODE 
});
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Временно заблокировать кнопку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747278/%d0%92%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: Можно заблокировать кнопку при событии клик, поставив setTimout на разблокировку.  И или еще хорошим тоном будет вызвать 'stop()' на анимируемом элементе для остановки анимации.

Answer (score 0):

debounce вам в впомощь
пример можно посмотреть здесь

https://learn.javascript.ru/task/debounce